# Custom woocommerce payment plugin for Lebanon

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a woocommerce plugin for an e-payment option specifically for a Lebanese bank based on sark migs, I reached a point where I am redirected to the bank portal, and once the test card number is used it gets me back to my website with " thank you your order has been received" (which is not my success message) woocommerce keeps the payment as pending and the bank portal doesn't update the transaction. the returned URL in woocomerce shows this error

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in C:\wamp\www\wordpress3\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 525

Is my problem related to this error ( I only modified in sark plugin and not in the functions) or is it related to the idea of authenticating the callback URL in my bank's portal ( I have read this part somewhere abt paypal)

Below is my code, any help is appreciated!

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'sark_migs_init', 0);

function sark_migs_init() {

    if ( !class_exists( 'WC_Payment_Gateway' ) ) return;

    class SarkMigs extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
        public function __construct() {         
            $this -> id           = 'sarkmigs';
            $this -> method_title = __('Sark Migs', 'sark');
            $this -> method_description  = __('', 'sark');
            $this -> icon         =  plugins_url( 'images/migs_logo.jpg' , __FILE__ );
            $this -> has_fields   = false;

            $this -> init_form_fields();
            $this -> init_settings();

            $this -> title                  = $this -> settings['title'];
            $this -> description            = $this -> settings['description'];             
            $this -> merchant_id            = $this -> settings['merchant_id'];
            $this -> access_code            = $this -> settings['access_code'];
            $this -> secure_hash_secret     = $this -> settings['secure_hash_secret'];  
            $this -> service_host           = $this -> settings['service_host'];
            $this -> success_message        = $this -> settings['thank_you_msg'];
            $this -> failed_message         = $this -> settings['transaction_failed_Msg'];

            $this -> msg['message'] = "";
            $this -> msg['class']   = "";

            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_sarkmigs', array( $this, 'check_sark_migs_response' ) );   
            add_action('valid-sarkmigs-request', array($this, 'successful_request'));

            if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.0.0', '>=' ) ) {
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            } else {
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways', array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }
            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_sarkmigs', array($this, 'receipt_page'));   
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $this,'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 ) );          
        }

        function init_form_fields() {

            $this -> form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title' => __('Enable/Disable', 'sark'),
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => __('Enable MIGS Payment Module.', 'sark'),
                    'default' => 'no'
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title' => __('Title:', 'sark'),
                    'type'=> 'text',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'MIGS', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'description' => __('Your desire title name .it will show during checkout proccess.', 'sark'),
                    'default' => __('Sark Migs', 'sark')
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title' => __('Description:', 'sark'),
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'description' => __('Pay securely by Credit Card/Debit Card through MasterCard Internet Gateway Service.', 'sark'),
                    'default' => __('Pay securely by Credit Card/Debit Card through MasterCard Internet Gateway Service.', 'sark')
                ),
                'merchant_id' => array(
                    'title' => __('Merchant ID', 'sark'),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'Merchant ID', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'description' => __('Merchant ID, Given by MIGS')
                ),
                'access_code' => array(
                    'title' => __('Access Code', 'sark'),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'Access Code', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'description' =>  __('Access Code, Given by MIGS', 'sark')
                ),
                'secure_hash_secret' => array(
                    'title' => __('Secure Hash Secret', 'sark'),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'Secure Hash Secret', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'description' =>  __('Encrypted/Secure Hash Secret key Given to Merchant by MIGS', 'sark')
                ),
                'service_host' => array(
                    'title' => __('MIGS URL', 'sark'),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'MIGS URL', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'description' =>  __('(For example: https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay) Given to Merchant by MIGS', 'sark'),
                    'default' => __('https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay', 'sark')
                ),
                'thank_you_msg' => array(
                    'title' => __('Transaction Success Message', 'sark'),
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'Transaction Success Message', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'description' =>  __('Put the message you want to display after a successfull transaction.', 'sark'),
                    'default' => __('Thank you for shopping with us. Your account has been charged and your transaction is successful. We will be shipping your order to you soon.', 'sark')
                ),
                'transaction_failed_Msg' => array(
                    'title' => __('Transaction Failed Message', 'sark'),
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'Transaction Failed Message', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'description' =>  __('Put whatever message you want to display after a transaction failed.', 'sark'),
                    'default' => __('Thank you for shopping with us. However, the transaction has been declined.', 'sark')
                )

            );

        }

        public function admin_options(){
            echo '<h3>'.__('MasterCard Internet Gateway Service', 'sark').'</h3>';          
            echo '<p>'.__('<a href="http://securenext.com/" target="_blank">This module developed by HIP </a> ').'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.__('MIGS is most popular payment gateway for online shopping').'</p>';
            echo '<table class="form-table">';
            $this -> generate_settings_html();
            echo '</table>';
        }

        function payment_fields() {
            if($this -> description) echo wpautop(wptexturize($this -> description));
        }

        function receipt_page($order) {         
            echo '<p>'.__('Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with MasterCard Internet Gateway Service.', 'sark').'</p>';
            echo $this -> generate_axis_gate_form($order);
        }

        function process_payment($order_id) {           
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);           
            return array('result' => 'success', 'redirect' => $order->get_checkout_payment_url( true ));



        }

        function check_sark_migs_response() {
            $authorised = false;            
            $md5Hash = $this->secure_hash_secret;
            $txnSecureHash = $_REQUEST['vpc_SecureHash'];

            $order_id = explode( '_', $_REQUEST['vpc_MerchTxnRef'] );
            $order_id = (int) $order_id[0];
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

            $DR = $this->parseDigitalReceipt();
            $ThreeDSecureData = $this->parse3DSecureData();

            /* Make sure user entered Transaction Success message otherwise use the default one */
            if( trim( $this->success_message ) == "" || $this->success_message == null ) {
                $this->success_message = "Thank you for shopping with us. Your account has been charged and your transaction is successful. We will be shipping your order to you soon.";
            }

            /* Make sure user entered Transaction Faild message otherwise use the default one */
            if( trim( $this->failed_message ) == "" || $this->failed_message == null ) {
                $this->failed_message = "Thank you for shopping with us. However, the transaction has been declined.";
            }

            $msg['class']   = 'error';
            $msg['message'] = $this->failed_message;

            if ( strlen($md5Hash) > 0 && $_REQUEST['vpc_TxnResponseCode'] != "7" && $_REQUEST['vpc_TxnResponseCode'] != "No Value Returned") {

                foreach( $_REQUEST as $key => $value ) {
                    if ( $key != "vpc_SecureHash" && strlen( $value ) > 0) {
                        $md5Hash .= $value;
                    }
                }

                if ( strtoupper( $txnSecureHash ) != strtoupper( md5( $md5Hash )) ) {
                    $authorised = false;
                } else {                    
                    if( $DR["txnResponseCode"] == "0" ) {                                   
                        $authorised = true;
                    } else {
                        $authorised = false;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                $authorised = false;
            }

            if( $authorised ) {
                try {
                    $order_status = $decryptValues['order_status'];
                    if( $order -> status !== 'completed' ) {
                        $transauthorised = true;
                        $msg['message'] = $this->success_message;
                        $msg['class'] = 'success';
                        if( $order -> status != 'processing' ) {
                            $order -> payment_complete();
                            $order -> add_order_note('MIGS Payment successful<br/>Receipt Number: '.$DR["receiptNo"]);
                            WC()->cart->empty_cart();
                        }
                    }
                } catch( Exception $e ) {
                    $msg['class'] = 'error';
                    $msg['message'] = $this->failed_message;

                    $order -> update_status('failed');
                    $order -> add_order_note('Payment Transaction Failed');
                    //$order -> add_order_note($this->msg['message']);
                }
            } else {
                $msg['class'] = 'error';
                $msg['message'] = $this->failed_message;

                $order -> update_status('failed');
                $order -> add_order_note('Payment Transaction Failed');
                //$order -> add_order_note($this->msg['message']);
            }

            if ( function_exists( 'wc_add_notice' ) ) {
                wc_add_notice( $msg['message'], $msg['class'] );
            }
            else {
                if($msg['class']=='success') {
                    WC()->add_message( $msg['message']);
                }else {
                    WC()->add_error( $msg['message'] );
                }
                WC()->set_messages();
            }

            wp_redirect( $order->get_checkout_order_received_url() );
            exit;       
        }

        function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) { 
            // make action magic happen here... 
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'test_meta_when_land_thankyou', 'Saved_data' );
        }
public function generate_axis_gate_form($order_id) {    

            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
            $order_id = $order_id.'_'.date("ymds");
            $order_amount = 1 * $order->order_total;
            //$order_amount = $order->order_total;
            //$exploded_order = explode('=', $order->get_checkout_order_received_url());

            $md5Hash = $this->secure_hash_secret;

            /* Make sure user entered MIGS url, otherwise use the default one */
            if( trim( $this->service_host ) == "" || $this->service_host == null ) {
                $this->service_host = "https://gw1.audicards.com/TPGWeb/payment/prepayment.action?";
            }
            $service_host = "https://gw1.audicards.com/TPGWeb/payment/prepayment.action?";

            $num1 = date("Ymd");
            $num2 = (rand(1000,9999));
            $num3 = "-";
            $orderinforandnum = $num1 . $num3 . $num2;

            get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

            $DigitalOrder = array(
                "version" => "1",
                "locale" => "en",
                "command" => "pay",
                "accessCode" => $this->access_code,
                "merchTxnRef" => $order_id,
                "merchant" => $this->merchant_id,
                "orderInfo" => $orderinforandnum,
                "amount" => $order_amount,              
                "returnURL" => $order->get_checkout_order_received_url(),
                "currency" => get_woocommerce_currency(),
            );
        $SECURE_SECRET = "******";
        $appendAmp = 0;
        $vpcURL = "";
        $newHash = "";
        $md5Hash = $SECURE_SECRET;  
        ksort ( $DigitalOrder );    
        foreach($DigitalOrder as $key => $value) 
        {
            // create the md5 input and URL leaving out any fields that have no value
            if (strlen($value) > 0 && ($key == 'accessCode' || $key == 'merchTxnRef' || $key == 'merchant' || $key == 'orderInfo' || $key == 'amount' || $key == 'returnURL')) {
                print 'Key: '.$key.'  Value: '.$value."<br>";
                // this ensures the first paramter of the URL is preceded by the '?' char
                if ($appendAmp == 0) 
                {
                    $vpcURL .= urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
                    $appendAmp = 1;
                } else {
                    $vpcURL .= '&' . urlencode($key) . "=" . urlencode($value);
                }
                $md5Hash .= $value;
            }
        }   
        $newHash .= $vpcURL."&vpc_SecureHash=" . strtoupper(md5($md5Hash));
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">window.location.href='https://gw1.audicards.com/TPGWeb/payment/prepayment.action?$newHash'</script>";
        exit;
        }   

        private function parseDigitalReceipt() {
            $dReceipt = array(
                "amount"            => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_Amount'] ),
                "locale"            => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_Locale'] ),
                "batchNo"           => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_BatchNo'] ),
                "command"           => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_Command'] ),
                "message"           => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_Message'] ),
                "version"           => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_Version'] ),
                "cardType"          => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_Card'] ),
                "orderInfo"         => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_OrderInfo'] ),
                "receiptNo"         => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_ReceiptNo'] ),
                "merchantID"        => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_Merchant'] ),
                "authorizeID"       => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_AuthorizeId'] ),
                "merchTxnRef"       => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_MerchTxnRef'] ),
                "transactionNo"     => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_TransactionNo'] ),
                "acqResponseCode"   => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_AcqResponseCode'] ),
                "txnResponseCode"   => $this->null2unknown( $_REQUEST['vpc_TxnResponseCode'] )
            );
            return $dReceipt;
        }

        private function parse3DSecureData() {
            $threeDSecure = array(
                "verType"           => array_key_exists( "vpc_VerType", $_REQUEST )          ? $_REQUEST['vpc_VerType']          : "No Value Returned",
                "verStatus"         => array_key_exists( "vpc_VerStatus", $_REQUEST )        ? $_REQUEST['vpc_VerStatus']        : "No Value Returned",
                "token"             => array_key_exists( "vpc_VerToken", $_REQUEST )         ? $_REQUEST['vpc_VerToken']         : "No Value Returned",
                "verSecurLevel"     => array_key_exists( "vpc_VerSecurityLevel", $_REQUEST ) ? $_REQUEST['vpc_VerSecurityLevel'] : "No Value Returned",
                "enrolled"          => array_key_exists( "vpc_3DSenrolled", $_REQUEST )      ? $_REQUEST['vpc_3DSenrolled']      : "No Value Returned",
                "xid"               => array_key_exists( "vpc_3DSXID", $_REQUEST )           ? $_REQUEST['vpc_3DSXID']           : "No Value Returned",
                "acqECI"            => array_key_exists( "vpc_3DSECI", $_REQUEST )           ? $_REQUEST['vpc_3DSECI']           : "No Value Returned",
                "authStatus"        => array_key_exists( "vpc_3DSstatus", $_REQUEST )        ? $_REQUEST['vpc_3DSstatus']        : "No Value Returned"
            );
            return $threeDSecure;
        }

        private function responseDescription( $responseCode ) {
            switch ( $responseCode ) {
case "0" : $result = "Transaction Successful"; break;
                case "?" : $result = "Transaction status is unknown"; break;
                case "1" : $result = "Unknown Error"; break;
                case "2" : $result = "Bank Declined Transaction"; break;
                case "3" : $result = "No Reply from Bank"; break;
                case "4" : $result = "Expired Card"; break;
                case "5" : $result = "Insufficient funds"; break;
                case "6" : $result = "Error Communicating with Bank"; break;
                case "7" : $result = "Payment Server System Error"; break;
                case "8" : $result = "Transaction Type Not Supported"; break;
                case "9" : $result = "Bank declined transaction (Do not contact Bank)"; break;
                case "A" : $result = "Transaction Aborted"; break;
                case "C" : $result = "Transaction Cancelled"; break;
                case "D" : $result = "Deferred transaction has been received and is awaiting processing"; break;
                case "F" : $result = "3D Secure Authentication failed"; break;
                case "I" : $result = "Card Security Code verification failed"; break;
                case "L" : $result = "Shopping Transaction Locked (Please try the transaction again later)"; break;
                case "N" : $result = "Cardholder is not enrolled in Authentication scheme"; break;
                case "P" : $result = "Transaction has been received by the Payment Adaptor and is being processed"; break;
                case "R" : $result = "Transaction was not processed - Reached limit of retry attempts allowed"; break;
                case "S" : $result = "Duplicate SessionID (OrderInfo)"; break;
                case "T" : $result = "Address Verification Failed"; break;
                case "U" : $result = "Card Security Code Failed"; break;
                case "V" : $result = "Address Verification and Card Security Code Failed"; break;
                default  : $result = "Unable to be determined";
            }
            return $result;
        }

        private function null2unknown($data) {
            if ($data == "") {
                return "No Value Returned";
            } else {
                return $data;
            }
        }

        function get_pages($title = false, $indent = true) {
            $wp_pages = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order');
            $page_list = array();
            if ($title) $page_list[] = $title;
            foreach ($wp_pages as $page) {
                $prefix = '';
                // show indented child pages?
                if ($indent) {
                    $has_parent = $page->post_parent;
                    while($has_parent) {
                        $prefix .=  ' - ';
                        $next_page = get_page($has_parent);
                        $has_parent = $next_page->post_parent;
                    }
                }
                // add to page list array array
                $page_list[$page->ID] = $prefix . $page->post_title;
            }
            return $page_list;
        }

    }

    function woocommerce_add_sark_migs_gateway($methods) {
        $methods[] = 'SarkMigs';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_add_sark_migs_gateway' );

}
```

Comment: Looking quickly, `add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $this,'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 ) ); ` is wrong for sure. It should be `add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $this,'action_woocommerce_thankyou' ), 10, 1 );` Whether that is your only problem I couldn't say, but it's likely that it's causing the error message you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to modify what you told me but still the same result, any thoughts?